# phase shift in LRC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, filter

I need to use a L-R-C tank in my design and I'm having trouble with the calculations. And I think it is because of the phase shift I didn't take into account.
[image: RLC]
Here you can see there is a differential equation introduced to extract the current-wave-charge equation. To my calculations the frequency is correct but I also need to know the phase shift \$ \theta \$ as well.

This is supposed to be the voltage wave of my LRC circuit:

```
ww = 660.764; vc = 30; slip = 0.99; result = 
 Cos[ww*t]*
  vc*(Exp[-t*((0.461 + (ww*slip)*
          ww*1715.38/(66564 + 
             6648.72*(ww*
                 slip)^2))/(2*(134*10^-5 + (5420 + (ww*
                  slip)^2*5.385)/(66564 + 
              6648.72*(ww*slip)^2))))]); Plot[result, {t, 0, Pi/ww}]
```

[image: Shift]
However, as you can see, the cosine wave is slightly shifted and it messes with my further calculations. So, what is the equation for the phase shift \$ \theta \$ ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhPDQW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I added the example schematic. In the initial condition, VC is 30V. Then I showed the graph of VC. VC is charged up to 30V in initial state and then slowly dies.

[image: waveform]

This above graph is taken from circuit lab simulation of the circuit above. This is the correct waveform with no phase shift because the simulator included the phase shift into equation. How can I so?

Comment: Speaking about "phase shift" it is necessary to state which signals you want to compare. Phase shift is always the phase difference between two signals of the same frequency.

Comment: @LvW I meant that instead of A*Cos[ww*t] the wavefowm is seen like Cos[ww*t+\$\theta\$] and by phase shift I meant this \$\theta\$ in the formula.

Comment: Show the actual circuit used and make it clear where the input is and where the output is. Include all (or any) loads and any impedances in series with the stimulus voltage.

Comment: @Andyaka I edited the question and added the schematic.

Comment: If you're actually implementing this circuit in the physical realm.... good luck finding those sub-ohm resistors!

Comment: As far as I have understood - the circuit has no input. Hence, we assume that the capacitor has a certain initial charge (voltage) and the question is how the oscilattion dies out. If my assumption is true, for a clear understanding it would be best to include a switch which closes at t=0. Alper91 - again, when you want to know something about the phase  of any quantity within the circuit (voltage or current) you must specify the reference quantity (voltage or current). Otherwise, mentioning of a phase shift makes no sense!

Comment: @LvW Edited according to your suggestions bu I still disagree with you in phase shift. Since a clear cosine wave is 'Shifted' in time.

Comment: Alper91 - don`t you think that any shift in time or phase is identical to a DIFFERENCE between two time slots resp. two phase responses?

Comment: @LvW So what do you think a phase DIFFERENCE is?

Comment: When I compare two periodic signals that are not in phase, there is a certain phase difference (expressed in deg) which is called "phase shift". Of course, in many cases it is convenient to declare the phase position of one of the two signals to zero. But his is an arbritrary choice.

Comment: Alper91-can you explain how and why the phase appears in your solution for q=q(t)?

Comment: @LvW actually, the problem is that I don't include the phase shift. I'm writing a paper and using mathematical equations to explain the circuit. However, the problem is I don't know how can I calculate the phase shift. That's what I ask. I can calculate \$\omega\$ correctly but \$\theta\$ is missing. without theta the waveform looks shifted.

Comment: Alper91...why don`t you reply to my question? "Phase shift" is a DIFFERECE between two phases - one is shifted with repect to the other one. Tell us, which two signals you want to compare!!

Comment: @LvW Sir, I don't know how to explain it more clearly, really. My problem is that, in the above picture, the equation of \$\omega\$ is given but the equation of \$\theta\$ is not. Maybe its better to forget the phase shift and to focus on \$\theta\$

Comment: Alper91...there is no need for a long explanation....while speaking of a "phase shift" you only must specify the two signals which are phase shifted against each other. I cannot understand how you can mention a "phase shift" without knowing what you mean..

Comment: At first glance, your voltage waveform looks exactly the same as the other one. Can you highlight the difference more clearly? If you think there is a shift, you can convert it to degrees using deltaT/T*360, where delta T is the time shift, T is the period of the resonant frequency, and 360 is 360 degrees.

Comment: I believe the simulator assumed Theta is zero. It clearly looks like it starts at cosine(0).

Comment: @mkeith No they are not. There is definetely a phase shift. As you can see the frequency calculation is given and it is correct however, \$ \theta \$ is not given. And you are also correct, LtSpice and other simulation softwares does not compute the phase shift. However, the equations clearly indicates a phase shift. I can see it in mathematica but not in LtSpice.

Comment: Read through this and tell me if it makes any sense: "This above graph is taken from circuit lab simulation of the circuit above. This is the correct waveform with no phase shift because the simulator included the phase shift into equation. How can I so?"

Comment: Since I(L1)=I(C1)   I would expect Vc(t) to lag current 90 deg but IL is inverted (should be negative peak Ic=CdV/dt) so it looks like it is (mis) leading phase

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking. If the simulation result is correct, then the correct value of Theta is probably zero. This is just based on the appearance of the waveform. To be honest, your question is not very clear. Probably should just be closed if you are unable to clarify.

Comment: @mkeith Yes! Yes! a thousand times yes! Circuit lab produces the correct waveform, because it includes the phase shift. But the problem is I can't include the phase shift in mathematica because I don't know how to calculate the phase shift \$ \theta \$. I confirm that I calculate the frequency correctly but not the phase shift. All I need is the equation of \$ \theta \$ above in the question: \$ q = q_{max} e^{(\frac{-t R}{2 L})} cos(w t + \theta)\$

Comment: You showed a graph of your calculated result. Did you basically assume theta = zero? Or if not, what did you assume about theta?

Comment: I assumed theta as zero. That's why I was able to see the phase shift! And I confirmed from the calculation results there were some mistakes in the equation. The mistake is not including the theta!

Comment: What phase shift exactly did you see?

Comment: it changes by the slip ratio, from 0 to smt 20-30 degrees as far as I see.

Comment: I think your code or your math is just wrong but I am too lazy to check it. The simulators are doing it right. Your question, even now, is kind of hard to understand. Just double-check all your math and maybe study how to do circuit analysis of inductors and capacitors with initial conditions.

Comment: Cosine (wt) is one at t=0. What is more, the derivative of cos(wt) at t=0 is 0. Your graph is OBVIOUSLY not a graph of cos(wt) at t=0. Maybe that is due to the exponential decay term. Maybe you just calculated the exponential decay incorrectly. Sort it out.

Comment: @mkeith I understand this non-problem perfectly. So bear with me. The voltage is not a sinusoid but the practical of one with an exponential decay. Therefore both his and mine have dv/dt=0 for only a few pixels. They are identical in shape and amplitude as far as the eye can see. The only problem is several people misunderstand this and are expecting a sinewave starting at cos of 0 deg when there is an \$ coefficient \$e^{-t\tau}\$ in the damped cosine wave from 0 current thus 0 phase! But 30V charge.  Ok yet?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I do get what you are saying. And I don't expect you to read through 200 comments on the OP. But the original poster said that his/her calculated results do not match the simulation results presented. They look fairly close to me, actually, and I said that in the comment section. OP said "no" they are definitely not the same, there is a phase shift. Well, I think there is just some calculation error, maybe not a big one, that makes the OP's calculation differ from the simulation. As far as slope of Voltage at T=0, I get that the decay makes the slope < 0. But not by much.

Comment: Anyway, the OP is not going to accept any of these answers. The bounty will be automatically awarded to whoever has the most upvotes, I guess.

Comment: Where it says “practical” , I wrote “product of” and iPad changed it. But in reality and exponential decay has no zero slope at the start, but the cosine product almost looks like a zero slope in the 1st pixels. I think it is still a misunderstanding and there is no error AFAIK in the result, within the graphical resolution limits. Mine has the Peak +-  current and voltage limits on the traces to much higher resolution and so the only error I see is the current polarity .

Comment: the exponential product with a cosine “appears like “ a phase shift, but it is not the Theta in his equation.

Comment: Alper do you understand my answer and comments. Any questions?  equation of θ =0 due to initial current=0 conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The takeaways you should get from this answer for an underdamped sinusoidal 2nd order response are;

- there was no "error" in the question for the values or slopes or initial conditions or his calculations. It was his expectation that was *perplexed*.
- The formula with some phase offset almost looked like the response but in fact, there is no initial phase shift.

  - It is not a cosine that starts at some lag angle for theta, so it= 0
  - It is a product of a decaying exponential \$e^{-t/\tau}\$ times a cosine wave so the slope just at t=0 for switch closure IMMEDIATELY starts to decay at some rate, \$V/τ=dV/dt=Ic/C\$
- The 2nd plot shows  I(L1) which was defined in the opposite direction of I(C1),

  - both dV/dt and Ic are negative. (-ve ) just after t=0
- except for above, my simulation is exactly the same as given, only by plot scale & resolution

You should expect capacitor **current phase to always lead voltage phase by 90 deg.** This is due to the current being the rate of change of voltage property. Your IL(t) reference direction was reversed such that discharging capacitor current was shown positive but should have been negative.

$$I_C=C\cdot dV/dt$$ By convention a negative slope for capacitor voltage decay creates a negative current. So your trace pairs looked like they were (mis) leading phase instead of lagging.

The frequency of the underdamped decay is; $$f=\dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}}$$

However in your formula, since the initial condition for Ic current was 0, thus  **θ = 0**.

[image]
Sorry for the pun.

Falstad is consistent with your inverted plot above.

[image]

- My Falstad Simulations show the peak levels on the left.
- The oscillating cycle period is just < 10ms as expected.

Comment: OP is asking about phase shift between voltage plot he or she calculated using the formula in the original post and the VOLTAGE PLOT in the simulation result. OP is not asking about phase shift between voltage and current.

Comment: @mkeith I realize that and addressed the initial conditions for 0 zero is 0 phase offset when switch is closed.  Not only his plot agree with his formula by my plot agreed with his plot and his schematic except for his direction of +ve current. So where’s your answer?   if I may ask.

Answer (score 1):

You have in an unknown way got a solution formula where the unknown angle and the max charge in C are the freely selectable parameters. Physically they can be derived from the circuit current and capacitor's charge at t=0. We call generally them "initial conditions" and both are needed.

Your cryptic program code doesn't at least produce right plot for a case where inductor current is zero at t=0. I must admit I cannot see any connection between the code and the circuits in the question.

If you want symbolic solution formula for a differential equation and take automatically initial conditions into the account as explicit variables, try Laplace transform method. There you must input the initial conditions as symbols as soon as you convert the equation to s-domain.

You have also another circuit which has three inductors. It's not equivalent with your first circuit which has only one. If the 3 inductor version happens to be the right one which presents your practical problem, do not expect any manageably simple formula to exist for VC. It can be easily calculated only numerically as you did with the simulator. You can do the same for ex. in Excel or Mathematica if you present your circuit as a group of state variable equations where the derivatives of the capacitor voltage and inductor currents are expressed as a function of cumulated values. You can step through the evolution of the state variables by integrating numerically.

If you wanted formulas for tuning the actual performance measures, which you haven't revealed at all, you have two possiblities:

1. forget it, search the needed component values with simulations
2. use approximate simplified circuit where R1, R2, L1. L2 and L3 are replaced by one L and one R. Do it after you have with simulations confirmed yourself the result is accurate enough, not before!

Comment: I found his plot is accurate except for polarity of I.

Comment: The programmed plot is wrong or the inductors have initial current.

Comment: Both his and my plot start at 0 A. Pls explain. Mine is shown, his looks like 0. And both peak ~ -14A

Comment: I can see it wrongly. But the voltage plot just above text "however as you can see" seems to start  non horizontally

Comment: T=10ms is start time.  Plot above you state is L current in wrong polarity. Not voltage . Try to understand

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 the problematic plot has value 30 (unit=unknown) at t=0, drops, reaches 0 at t=2.4 ms . The plot covers time interval 0...5 ms, there's nothing plotted at t=10 ms.

Comment: ignore the 1st plot and look at the 2nd pair of plots which match mine. the 1st plot only covers a half sine voltage up to 5ms in a 10ms period

Comment: The "3 inductor version" + 1 C **still has an equivalent circuit of a 2nd order response**

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 That's something new, I haven't seen nor done it. Can you show it or provide a link? I didn't find find acceptably right frequency nor decaying time constant which reproduce VC when the capacitor has initially 30V and the inductor currents were all zero.

Comment: No link. I just know that from its shared node and equivalent inductance as you would with any equivalent R network with voltage and current sources. So a CLLL network is equivalent to CL 2nd order but a LCLL or a CLC or a CLCC network would be 3rd order using lumped equivalent circuits. SO reduction is necessary. Not just counting all reactors. Ones with shared nodes can be combined. This is a simplification that usually works.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 you are looking at the wrong thing. The OP question is totally unclear. OP is comparing self-generated result with voltage waveform from simulation. Your answer assumes the OP is comparing the phase of the current and voltage waveforms.

Comment: And irrespective, the plot that the OP is showing is clearly wrong because, as user287001 says, the slope of the voltage across the capacitor is not zero, meaning that initial current is not zero in OP's simulation. The OP just screwed up the math somewhere.

Comment: It falls immediately due to asymptotic decay.  e^-(t/T). what problem? I don’t see any. Why do you not get this.

Comment: I do understand about the decay. I just think that the OP's plot looks much steeper from the get-go than your (and the OP's) simulation result. Anyway, this question is kind of a sh!t show.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is in error. You have fixated on the Theta term, but that is not your problem.

You present two circuits. The first is a simple RLC circuit. You present a circuit analysis of that simple circuit which neglects initial conditions (in particular the initital current through the inductor).
[image]

THEN, you show a second circuit which is not equivalent to the first, and you are concerned because the simulation result does not match the calculations and your own simulation based on the FIRST circuit which is different.
[image]

Because of the circuit differences, you should have no expectation that the simulation you calculated yourself and the actual simulation results should match. Why don't you try simulating a simple RLC circuit and see if your calculated results match the simulation result when you assume the phase at t=0 is 0?